# Load Image Icon in Swing dependent on Operatin System in use

Tags: java, swing, operating-system, imageicon

have a little question concerning image icons in java and how to put a restriction on what image icon can be choosen from a drop down menu in my swing application.

I am developing a multi platform java program and for the life of cant work out how to restrict the icon you may select from a drop down menu according to the operatin system in use.

For eg. If I select a linux icon on say a Windows based PC the user should get a litte message saying this is not linux but windows select again.

My code so far works in that it will load the icon no errors etc

```
    private String img[] = {
    "default.png",
    "window.png",
    "linix.png",
    "macos.png",
    "solaris.png"};

private ImgIcon[] icon = {
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img[0])),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img[1])),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img[2])),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img[3])),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(img[4]))};

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
if (IsWin())  {
    jTextArea1.setText("Detected OS : " + os);
    }
else if (IsMac()) {
    jTextArea1.setText("Detected OS : " + os);
    }
else if (IsLin()) {
    jTextArea1.setText("Detected OS : " + os);
    }
else  if(IsSol()) {
    jTextArea1.setText("\Detected OS : " + os);
    }
}
```

[image]

So far so good it works when you select the icon it displays and you get a little message in the JTextArea telling you what your Operating system is...just need to somehow alert the user they have choosen the wrong operating system icon if they are on another operating system!

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: OS-detection is quite simple: `System.getProperty("os.name");`. Now, if you know in advance the OS, why do you need a combo box to choose from?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks for such a quick reply..I am using System.getProperty("os.name"); through out my program just trying to place a restriction if the user selects the wrong image ie they select the Linux icon and are on mac or windows based machines

Comment: Don't let the user be wrong. Let yourself be right and automatically choose the correct image for him :-)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  Ok thanks for your suggestion will tick the box as best answer. I had the same similar code your using below in another part of the program. Just wanted user to do a little something as 99 precent of the program is doing all the work in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (osName.indexOf("Mac OS") > -1) {
        // Mac OS
    } else if (osName.indexOf("Windows") > -1) {
        // Windows
    } else if (osName.indexOf("Linux") > -1) {
        // Linux
    } else if (osName.indexOf("Solaris") > -1) {
        // Solaris
    } else {
        // Something else
    }
```

You can get a more complete list of those values [here](http://www.javaneverdie.com/java/java-os-name-property-values/)

Seems to me that your combobox is unnecessary if you don't want the user to select the wrong value and you know which OS you are on.